# In Jetty 6.1.14, how can you get a basic file/we server running alongside a Java webapp?

Tags: jetty

HP Operations Orchestration 9.07 (now near EOL) runs in a Jetty 6.1.14 webapp on port 8443.

How can I get Jetty 6.1.14 to run a separate, basic web/file server on port 80?

What I have done so far in the `jetty.xml` config file has been unsuccessful:

```
<Configure id="FileServer" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="port">80</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
          <Array type="org.mortbay.jetty.ResourceHandler">
            <Item>
              <New id="Contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ResourceHandler"/>
            <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
        <Set name="welcomeFiles">
          <Array type="String"><Item>index.html</Item></Array>
        </Set>
            <Set name="resourceBase">.</Set>
          </New>
            </Item>
<Item>
<New class="org.mortbay.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"></New>
</Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <Call name="addLifeCycle">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
          <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
          <Set name="webAppDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

This has come from a combination of courses, including https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Configuring_a_File_Server_with_XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on help received in a Google+ community regarding this [question](https://plus.google.com/100471887743252791074/posts/chP4B8ecVCU), it is not possible in Jetty 6.1.14.

> *directoriesListed* option did not exist in Jetty6.

Answer (score 1):

That version of Jetty is over 6 years old, and Jetty 6 itself has been EOL for over 4 years.  We are releasing milestone versions of Jetty 9.3.x now which contain HTTP/2 support.

Referencing the Jetty 7/8 documentation will be difficult since we migrated over to the Eclipse foundation between 6 and 7 so all of the packaging changed, not to mention how the modules themselves were sliced up. Jetty 6 documentation can still be found here:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Documentation

This is the section you would want to look at:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Static+Content

Basically, you need to register either a DefaultServlet to serve the static content, or wire up a ResourceHandler to do the same.  Both will require you to set up a context to serve the static content from.

Comment: I know it's very old - like I said, it's used by HP OO 9.x (which is nearing its EOL, too): and I'm trying to avoid needing to spin-up a second webserver alongside Jetty to serve on port 80 on the same server